# Error 404 for every requests on the VPS, not on localhost

Tags: jhipster

I ve managed to install and run my Jhipster application on a Debian VPS. The homepage shows.
But when I'm trying to authenticate I m getting a :

> /app/rest/account 404 (Not
>   Found)

As it works on my computer, I m trying to find out why it doesn't on the VPS.

Are there settings to do on the VPS?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.  How did you install and run JHipster?  Are you using the development or production profile?  Are you using a frontend web server like Apache or Nginx?  Are there any errors in your logs?

Comment: On my computer I built the war with mvn -Pprod package. Development profile. I renamed the myapp.war.original war to myapp.war. I copied this war on my vps (/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps). On my vps i have a tomcat7 http server , jre1.7 and mysql 5.5 . The application launches (homepage is showing) but when I m trying to authenticate I have the 404 error.  I ve installed ubuntu on my computer and installed the exact same config (tomcat/jre/mysql) and my jhipster app works well there. My guess is that there is something wrong with the debian VPS settings.

Comment: I have replace debian with ubuntu on the vps, it works fine...